# Using Visual Studio Online's vNext tasks to deploy a database to Azure

Tags: azure, msbuild, azure-devops

I have a solution in `Visual Studio Online` and one of the projects is a `SQL Server Database Project`.

I am using the `vNext` Build and Release tasks to build, unit test and deploy my web application to Azure.

My question is - how can I use `vNext` tasks to automate the deployment of my database project to Azure? Should I leverage the `MSBuild` task somehow passing the proper arguments? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several ways to do this. As you said, you can use MSBuild task with some arguments to publish your SQL project during build. You can also add a deploy target in your sqlproj file, the target will run after build completes. Or you can also add a "Batch Script" step in your build definition to run "SqlPackage.exe" to publish the dacpac file that generated during the build. Refer to [this article](https://mohamedradwan.wordpress.com/2014/11/06/deploying-ssdt-during-local-and-server-build/) for details.

Comment: But what about firewall rules ? Do we need a additional PowerShell script to remotely add the current IP to the Azure SQL Server firewall ?